# Openedge application to sum 2 numbers

Tags: openedge

iam new to open edge, iam trying to write a program with two text boxes and a label. So I want to get the values from the two text boxes and calculate the sum and display it on a label.

I defined 3 Var ,2 for text boxes and 1 for carrying the sum

Comment: Don’t just talk about the code that you are wanting help with, show it to us. You will get much better responses that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i1 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO . 
DEFINE VARIABLE i2 AS INTEGER NO-UNDO . 

DEFINE VARIABLE iSum AS INTEGER NO-UNDO . 

UPDATE i1 i2 WITH SIDE-LABELS.

ASSIGN iSum = i1 + i2 . 

DISPL iSum.
```